# How to show Time format in Range Seek Bar?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I want to put 2 drawables in my sek bar. First will be minimum time and second drawable will show Max time selected by user. For this I am using [THIS LIBRARY.](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar) But No luck. How can I get my desired result ? What I did is here.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Setup the new range seek bar
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<>(this);
    // Set the range
    rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(15, 90);
    rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(20);
    rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(88);

    // Add to layout
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.seekbar_placeholder);
    layout.addView(rangeSeekBar);

    // Seek bar for which we will set text color in code
    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBarTextColorWithCode = (RangeSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBarTextColorWithCode);
    rangeSeekBarTextColorWithCode.setTextAboveThumbsColorResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);


    rangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<Integer> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            int hours = minValue / 4; // it will return hours.
            int minutes = (minValue % 4) * 15;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hours + " Hours - " + hours + ":" + minutes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: how about asking the ones who made the library ? xD

Comment: Instead of writing some unreliable logic / library, why  don't you use time-picker ?  
https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html

Comment: Its my requirement sir

Answer (score 2):

To get desired result you have to convert your minimum time and maximum time to minute.

```
String start[] = "6:00".split(":");
int min = Integer.parseInt(start[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(start[1]);
String end[] = "23:49".split(":");
int max = Integer.parseInt(end[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(end[1]);

rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(min);
rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(max);
```

Now in

```
onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<Integer> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue)
{
int minHour=minValu/60; //since both are ints, you get an int
int minMinute=minValu % 60;

int maxHour=maxValu/60; //since both are ints, you get an int
int maxMinute= maxValu % 60 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... but let me know what is exactly min(...) and max(...)

Comment: min and max are two 'int' variable. The time inside bracket it just for reference. Updated answer

Comment: oh git it. suppose I passed two value respectively minimum to mamimum like morning 06:00 AM to night 11:59 PM,.. How can I convert this ?

Comment: just convert your time to 24 hour clock and it will work, like 06:00 to 23:59

Comment: so how can I put this value in minimum and maximum area in rangebar ?

Comment: Should I pass these converted int into min and max value ?

Comment: Thank you for such a great help bro.. How to show Toast on every seek change listener that this time has been selected ?.

Comment: Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, minHour+": hrs "+minMinute+" min" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Yes, correct. Please accept the answer if you got meaningful info

Comment: Do you have any sample which don't have any library for this ?

Comment: As per my knowledge android does not have native RageSeekBar, so you have to use library.

Comment: Anyways, Thank you